# Installed Linux Mint (debian) "Reboot and Select proper Boot device..."

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, linux-mint

> "Reboot and Select proper boot device or Insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key  "

This is what I get, once I installed Linux Mint from a Live USB pendrive. On this machine **GigaByte BXBT-2807** [ [http://www.amazon.com/Gigabyte-Intel-Celeron-Barebones-GB-BXBT-2807/dp/B00KR0QHXW/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KR0QHXW) ]

I tried (F12) (keyboard works fine)and I got:

> UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
>
> UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell  [yes, twice]
>
> KINGSTONDataTraveller 3.01.00 [my usb pendrive]
>
> PO: HGST HCC4545421AZ45
>
> Enter Setup

Then :

- I tried to boot from the USB pendrive,
- I tried to boot from the default UEFI, 
  brief I tried the 4 options (UEFI, HDD and USB live CD), I get the same message. I tried a second UEFI and I Get `Shell>`terminal-like.
- I tried to remove/reinsert the *disky battery* to reset BIOS (?), no success.

Now I cannot reinstall Linux nor boot from anywhere.

What should I do ?

Thanks --

Answer (score 0):

I succeed by doing:

1. Remade your USB live pendrive (EFI was missing).
2. Install Linux USB->HDD
3. Relaunch freshly-installed Linux HDD

This remade the EFI's. It now works.